# Cannot Update Image from Runnable - Android

Tags: java, android

I have the following class that implements runnable. When I start the thread I get an error preventing me from updating the image. I have tried setting the image as you will see in the `runOnUiThread` function but it doesn't work. I would like to ultimately update the image every x seconds but I cannot seem to do this unless I put the thread inside the main activity class. Once I move it out nothing I try works.

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    MainActivity activity;
    ArrayList<Media> media = new ArrayList<Media>();
    public Test(MainActivity activity){

        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void run(){

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImageView img= (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In `MainActivity.java`'s `onCreate()` function I start the thread.

```
    Test p = new Test(this);
    Thread t = new Thread(p);
    t.start();
```

Then my error:

```
2019-10-31 19:26:47.274 5407-5407/com.desotomatrix.digitalsignageplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.desotomatrix.digitalsignageplayer, PID: 5407
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.desotomatrix.digitalsignageplayer.Test$1.run(Test.java:30)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:209)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7021)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:486)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:872)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing image on Android thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506961/changing-image-on-android-thread)

Comment: @JonGoodwin I had already tried the solution there but it's not really what I need. I need my code to run outside of a nested class.